# svg blur effect, set specific color

Tags: css, svg, svg-filters

I am starting to play with svg effects and animations and i found great example of how to apply blur effect to a svg path, but i have no idea how to set desired color instead of default black one.

```
<defs>
    <filter id="dropShadow">
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3" />
        <feOffset dx="2" dy="4" />
        <feMerge>
            <feMergeNode />
            <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
        </feMerge>
    </filter>
</defs>
```

As you can see in the included snippet i wanted to add lets say some green code of color to apply it as a blur color instead of black one, i was playing a little bit with svg docs but havent found working example.

Maybe someone could show how to implement color set in here ;)

```js
var screenCorners = [
    [50., 150.], 
    [450., 150.],
    [350., 50.],
    [ 150., 50.]
];

document.querySelector('#trapezoid').setAttribute('d', `
 M ${screenCorners[0][0]} ${screenCorners[0][1]}
 L ${screenCorners[1][0]} ${screenCorners[1][1]}
 L ${screenCorners[2][0]} ${screenCorners[2][1]}
 L ${screenCorners[3][0]} ${screenCorners[3][1]}
 Z
`);
```

```css
body {
 background:#333;
}

svg {
 width:500px;
 height:200px;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
}

#trapezoid {
 fill:none;
  stroke:white;
}
```

```html
<svg id="demo">
 <defs>
  <filter id="dropShadow">
   <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3" />
   <feOffset dx="2" dy="4" />
   <feMerge>
    <feMergeNode />
    <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
   </feMerge>
  </filter>
 </defs>
 <path id="trapezoid" filter="url(#dropShadow)"></path>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to add color to your shadow you need to use . In this example the shadow is white.

```js
var screenCorners = [
    [50., 150.], 
    [450., 150.],
    [350., 50.],
    [ 150., 50.]
];

document.querySelector('#trapezoid').setAttribute('d', `
 M ${screenCorners[0][0]} ${screenCorners[0][1]}
 L ${screenCorners[1][0]} ${screenCorners[1][1]}
 L ${screenCorners[2][0]} ${screenCorners[2][1]}
 L ${screenCorners[3][0]} ${screenCorners[3][1]}
 Z
`);
```

```css
body {
 background:#333;
}

svg {
 width:500px;
 height:200px;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
}

#trapezoid {
 fill:none;
  stroke:white;
}
```

```html
<svg id="demo">
 <defs>
  <filter id="dropShadow">
   <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3" result="blur1" />
      <feFlood flood-color="white" result="color"/>
      <feComposite in="color" in2="blur1" operator="in" result="sombra" />
   <feOffset dx="2" dy="4" />
   <feMerge>
    <feMergeNode />
    <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
   </feMerge>
  </filter>
    
 </defs>
 <path id="trapezoid" filter="url(#dropShadow)"></path>
</svg>
```